# Error : class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, java-8

On running my main program I am getting the above error. I am not sure what could be the reason for this.

On one of the pages online I found that the class files have been generated by a different version of the compiler and the current JDK is different

I deleted everything inside the **.m2 folder** and the **target** folder, but still, it showed the same error. Not sure maybe I should delete the **.idea** folder too and check.

There should be some way to resolve it without changing to Java 11.

This is the exact error -

```
java: cannot access org.hibernate.Session
bad class file: /C:/Users/name/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.CR1/hibernate-core-6.0.0.CR1.jar!/org/hibernate/Session.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Comment: Canyou show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @sp00m Changing to JDK 11 resolved the issue. You can post this as an answer and I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate 6.0 and later versions require at least Java 11 (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_system_requirements).

Comment: Could also provide some info on how hibernate is related to *jboss* . Separately I also find something weird on JBoss like https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html URL works but https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/reference/en/html/inheritance.html doesn't work whereas 4.0 is a later version of hibernate core. I am not sure why it's not added

Comment: @dnaiel From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)?oldformat=true), _JBoss, Inc. (now part of Red Hat) hired the lead Hibernate developers in order to further its development._. Concerning the docs, it seems they changed their URL in 4.0, try https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html.

Comment: So Hibernate is owned by JBoss as of now? And JBoss has merged with Red Hat?